# The spelling of Eliyahu's name

Tags: names, spelling-variants, eliyahu-hanavi, melachim-kings-book-of

Why is it that is some places in Melachim Eliyahu is spelled with a Vav and sometimes the Vav is missing?  I have looked in as many sources as I can think of and can not find an answer.

Examples:
Melachim Aleph Perek 17, 18,19,21,: with Vav
Melachim Bet Perek 1: no Vav
Melachim Bet Perek 2, 3, 9, 10: with Vav

Comment: http://www.learntorah.com/lt-shiur-details.aspx?id=6955

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6318/charvona-how-many-charvonas-were-there/6319#6319), different spellings of names that refer to the same person are not uncommon in Tanach. Deeper, esoteric meanings are associated with the changing of spellings. As a general rule, therefore, you will not find commentators of the *p'shat* approach that will address these spelling changes.

In this case , the most famous answer is that of the midrash quoted by [Rashi](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%A2:%D7%A8%D7%A9%22%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%95_%D7%9E%D7%91):

> בחמשה מקומות נכתב מלא ואליהו חסר בחמשה מקומות יעקב נטל אות משמו של אליהו ערבון שיבוא ויבשר גאולת בניו
>
> In five places ["Yaakov"] is written in full form [with a vav] and "Eliyahu" is written in lacking form [without a vav] in five places. Yaakov took a letter from Eliyahu's name as a guarantee that he will come and announce the redemption of his children.

For a more extensive explanation of this midrash, see [here](http://www.torah.org/learning/ravfrand/5763/bechukosai.html)