# What is the significance of leaving out the suffix-"vav" and/or adding it to אֲדֹנִיָּה?

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, king-david, melachim-kings-book-of

What is the significance of leaving out the suffix-"vav" and/or adding it to the name אֲדֹנִיָּה?

Of the 15 times the name of the antagonist or bad character is mentioned in 1 Kings 1, three times, it is אֲדֹנִיָּה without the "vav" ending, and twelve times with the "vav" ending, אֲדֹנִיָּהוּ.

What is the significance of this in regards to this particular person, אֲדֹנִיָּה? For example, if the adding of "vav" signifies something good (I do not know if that is true), did it mean therefore that at times אֲדֹנִיָּהוּ was good and when there was no "vav" to his name he was being bad?

A similar question, but not specifically to this character, that I found at Mi Yodeya is: [The spelling of Eliyahu's name](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11479/the-spelling-of-eliyahus-name)

Comment: side note https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4333606/jewish/Who-Was-Isaiah.htm#footnote16a4333606

Comment: This is a common phenomenon with many names: ירמיה, ירמיהו, חזקיה, חזקיהו, נתניה, נתניהו, עזריה, עזריהו